# What's the easiest way to export a CSV to Excel with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

I'm using Ruby 1.9 for this. I need to convert Ruby arrays into a Excel spreadsheet document (xls).

Comment: Do you need your script to open excel and ask it to import the values, or are you just wanting to make a CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use two gems to export to Excel-readable formats: [Spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/_index.html) (can create/parse .xls) and [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) (faster, but as far as I can remember doesn't work with .xls files)

Answer (score 2):

I've had excellent results with [WriteExcel](http://rubyforge.org/projects/writeexcel/) (which is a Ruby port of a Perl library of the same name).

Answer (score 0):

[Csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files would be the fastest if you just want to export values