# How to convert CSV to Excel?

Tags: ruby, excel, csv, rubygems

Is there any plugin in Ruby that converts CSV file onto Excel. I did little Google but all I found was converting Excel file into CSV. I know few gems which I can tweak a little and use to convert Excel to CSV but I need to know if anyone has done that before.

Comment: Usually we just let Excel import the CSV. Usually it just works.

Comment: Another almost-native alternative: XML import can produce "pretty" Excel documents too. I feed output from Rails' #to_xml into an XSLT to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646430/whats-the-easiest-way-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-with-ruby

Comment: Why dont you just use OLE? Excel can open csv files and save as xlsx file directly...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Excel often mangles CSV data. It will drop leading zeros, convert lowercase true/false to uppercase, convert big numbers to scientific notation, and probably more. By sending the user an XLS file, you can control the formatting and avoid losing data.

Comment: @texasbruce Excel OLE automation is Windows-only, and most folks are running Ruby on Mac or Linux. It also requires a paid license, while other options are free. Launching with OLE also has problems, like if you need to reactivate Office, launching it with OLE will hang Excel indefinitely, requiring manual intervention to get it working again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428997/whats-gem-can-operate-excel-on-linux), the [spreadsheet](https://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet) gem is a possibility. It looks like this is a very popular gem. Check it out. Example:

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet

header_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new(
  :weight => :bold,
  :horizontal_align => :center,
  :bottom => true,
  :locked => true
)

sheet1.row(0).default_format = header_format

FasterCSV.open(input_path, 'r') do |csv|
  csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
    sheet1.row(i).replace(row)
  end
end

book.write(output_path)
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886361/use-different-color-for-different-values-in-drop-down-for-excel-files-created), [write_xlsx](http://rubygems.org/gems/write_xlsx) is a possibility.

I've used the [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) with JRuby to export xls files. Here's a quick example.

```
require 'java'
require 'poi.jar'
# require 'poi-ooxml.jar'
require 'rubygems'
require 'fastercsv'

java_import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

wb = HSSFWorkbook.new # OR XSSFWorkbook, for xlsx
sheet = wb.create_sheet('Sheet 1')

FasterCSV.open(ARGV.first) do |csv|
  csv.each_with_index do |csv_row, line_no|
    row = sheet.createRow(line_no)
    csv_row.each_with_index do |csv_value, col_no|
      cell = row.createCell(col_no)
      cell.setCellValue(csv_value) unless csv_value.nil? # can't pass nil.
    end
  end
end


f = java.io.FileOutputStream.new("workbook.xls")
wb.write(f)
f.close
```

Some useful methods for formatting POI spreadsheets are

- `sheet.createFreezePane(0,1,0,1)`
- `wb.setRepeatingRowsAndColumns(0, -1, -1, 0, 1)`
- `sheet.setColumnWidth(i, 100 *256)`
- `sheet.autoSizeColumn(i)`, but beware, if you're running in headless mode, you have to call `java.lang.System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true")`

You can also use Win32ole on Windows, if you have Excel installed

```
require 'win32ole'
require 'rubygems'
require 'fastercsv'

xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = 0
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

FasterCSV.open(ARGV.first) do |csv|
  csv.each_with_index do |csv_row, line_no|
    csv_row.each_with_index do |value, col|
      ws.Cells(line_no + 1, col + 1).Value = value
    end
  end
end

wb.SaveAs("workbook.xls", 56) # 56 = xlExcel8 aka Excel 97-2003. i.e. xls
wb.SaveAs("workbook.xlsx", 51) # 51 = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
wb.SaveAs("workbook.xlsb", 50) # 50 = xlExcel12

wb.Close(2) #xlDoNotSaveChanges
xl.Quit
```

Some useful methods for formatting with Excel are

- `xl.Rows(1).Font.Bold = true`
- `ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit`

Yet another option is to write directly to Microsoft's [XML Spreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28v=office.10%29) format, as Ryan Bates at Railscasts.com does [at the end of his *Exporting CSV and Excel* episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Release Date</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product.id %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product.name %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"><%= product.released_on %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number"><%= product.price %></Data></Cell>
      </Row>
    <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

[This gem looks promising, too](https://github.com/randym/axlsx).

Comment: It seems like if you are using win32ole anyway you could just 'open' the csv file in excel and save it as xls. I'm not sure what the code would be though.

Comment: Good point. I hoped to just make the example look similar to the one above it, but opening the CSV directly into Excel is a smarter idea.

Comment: There is one more gem i found writeexcel did the job very easily.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't found any gem for convert CSV to EXCEL then you can try to find two gems separately

1. Read/Write CSV(For reading CSV file) e.g. [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/)
2. Read/Write EXCEL(For write EXCEL file) e.g. [SpreadSheet](https://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet)

Comment: Note that FasterCSV is built into Ruby 1.9 now as `require "csv"` in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

For those seeing this currently, the syntax changed a bit in these eight years. The following worked perfectly for me, based on the previous answer (recopied here for the sake of your copy-and-paste habits):

```
def convert_csv_to_xlsx
  book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
  sheet1 = book.create_worksheet

  header_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new(
    weight: :bold,
    horizontal_align: :center,
    bottom: :medium,
    locked: true
  )

  sheet1.row(0).default_format = header_format

  CSV.open(input_path, 'r') do |csv|
    csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
      sheet1.row(i).replace(row)
    end
  end

  book.write(output_path)
end
```

I.E.: FasterCSV is now just CSV and true for :bottom is deprecated

Answer (score -2):

The easy way is:

1. Open the CSV using your favorite text editor like Sublime Text. Notepad is okay
2. Replace all `,` (comma) to a tab `\t`
3. Save as it with extension `.xls`
4. Open the file using Excel and TADA! Here you go!