# NameError: uninitialized constant Roo::Spreadsheet::Workbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, csv, rake

I;m trying to convert my csv data to xslx file
but I keep getting the same error while I run my code.

my code look like this:

```
 def self.to_xslx(csv)

      book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new      
        
       sheet1 = book.create_worksheet
```

header_format = Spreadsheet::Format.new(

```
        :weight => :bold,
        :horizontal_align => :center,
        :bottom => true,
        :locked => true
    )

    sheet1.row(0).default_format = header_format

       FasterCSV.open(csv, 'r') do |csv| 

       csv.each_with_index do |row, i|

      sheet1.row(i).replace(row)

    end

    end

    book.write("../me.xlsx")
  end
```

I also require

```
include Roo

  require 'csv'
  require 'roo'
  require 'zip/zip'
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'spreadsheet'
  require 'yaml'
```

and have update gems :

```
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'spreadsheet', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert CSV to Excel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118158/how-to-convert-csv-to-excel)

Comment: @albertPaul nop.. The questioner was confused with the question topic. In the link you attach the answers are about how to change from excel to csv... 
And not like I asked